# Rstudio not connecting to CRAN

Tags: r, http, connection, cran

I get this error

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/XXXXX/Downloads/RPackages’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A connection with the server could not be established'
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A connection with the server could not be established'
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A connection with the server could not be established'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A connection with the server could not be established'
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A connection with the server could not be established'
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A connection with the server could not be established'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.4:
  cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/PACKAGES'
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/shinythemes_1.1.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 999652 bytes (976 KB)
downloaded 976 KB
```

That is, Rstudio keeps trying to connect to other URLs and only succeeds when it connects to https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/shinythemes_1.1.1.zip

Why is this the case?

I set my GLOBAL (CDN) Rstudio, Secure HTTP method and using Internet Explorer Proxy Settings for HTTP method.

Comment: Use a different mirror.

Comment: Go to the RGUI and test different repositories.

Answer (score -1):

It seems an index server crashed. You should use RGUI instead of RStudio to install package(s), set option firstly.

Comment: Hi thank you, what do you mean by an index server crashed? is this a temporary thing?

Comment: > sorry  I don't know how long time for this server, maybe SAS attacked this, ^-^, it's a joke. index server used to quickly find packages based your post.

Comment: This answer is very incomplete. Please update to explain what you mean by your second sentence. Also, do not assume every user has ready access to Rgui.

Comment: second sentence? the usage for index server? oh, you don't need use Rgui long time, only update packages with it, you can use Rstudio to develop again.  it seems the action of "install package in Rstudio" is ok now.